# Excel date value reflecting in formulabar

Tags: excel

I have a dates mentioned in column 'W'. The date is reflecting as 15-Feb-2017 and when I double click the cell or see the values in formula bar, it reflects as 2/15/2017. How can I fix it.

Comment: You would need to turn the date into a text string.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, in another column use this formula to convert an excel date to text format:

Assuming that the first date starts in row 1, otherwise change as needed:

```
=TEXT(W1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

Auto fill the rest of the column, by dragging down from the bottom right hand side of that cell to fill the column to the last row.

If you want, you can then copy this column and paste it back over the original column, pasting it as values.